# ng-change value not getting in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

In html

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000" class="form-control" ng-model="eachvalue.hours" ng-change="updateHour(eachvalue);" placeholder="Hours" required>
```

In Controller

```
 $scope.updateHour = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
```

I m not getting the value of 10.100 on controller when changing the number text box , here i can only console the value of 10.1

Can anyone know how to resolve the issue ?????????

Comment: Can you show some more controller code, especially the definition of eachvalue?

Comment: eachvalue  is an object in controller  , that is $scope.eachvalue = {};

Comment: Can you post `$scope.eachvalue` object ?

Answer (score 1):

By using `ng-model`, the value is already (two-way-)bound to `$scope.eachvalue.hours`. It will always be up-to-date, no need to use ng-change and pass a value to it.

```
 $scope.updateHour = function () {
  console.log($scope.eachvalue.hours);
 }
```

Comment: Then you probably have other constraints, not posted yet. May u provide a code sample showing your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your HTML also instaed

```
ng-change="updateHour(eachvalue)
```

**TO**

```
ng-change="updateHour(eachvalue.hours)
```

Comment: can u post your full code it will be easy to fix @JensonRaby

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define eachvalue.hours like that so you can bind to it:

```
$scope.eachvalue = { hours: 0 };
```